# RABL - custom collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I am trying to build the custom collection using RABL API.  I have an Idea model that has an array of idea_actions.  I need to append a custom collection of idea action using RABL, however I not seem to be able to use child :idea_actions because I need to be aware of the current action.  The code below errors... Any solution how can I get the custom collection i want?

```
object @idea

attributes *Idea.column_names

# need access to current action
node :idea_actions do
  @idea.idea_actions.each do |action|
    { :id => action.id}
    { :custom_stuff => action.some_method } if action.something?
  end
end

# can't do that...
# child :idea_actions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar use case. This what I had to do to get this to work:

**Solution 1**

- Introduce a partial for rendering the child attributes (**_idea_action.rabl**)

  ```
  attributes :id 
  if root_object.something?
    :custom_stuff => root_object.some_method 
  end
  ```
- Modify your main view to extend the new partial

  ```
  child(:idea_actions) { 
    extends("_idea_action")
  }
  ```

**Solution 2**

```
node :idea_actions do
  @idea.idea_actions.map do |action|
    { :id => action.id}.tap do |hash|
      hash[:custom_stuff] = action.some_method if action.something?
    end
  end
end
```

**Solution 3**

```
child :idea_actions do
  attributes :id
  node(:custom_stuff, :if => lambda {|action| action.something?}) do |action|
    action.some_method
  end
end
```

Comment: That will work only if I want standard attributes of the child model, not custom/conditional stuff.

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: Had a go. root_object in the given context is a collection of child items rather then the individual object.